# later.js - February and End of Month

Tags: javascript, date, time, recurrence, laterjs

I am creating a platform for recurring monthly orders.

I am using later.js for the recurrence. I have come across the following two cases and I am wondering if anybody has suggestions on how to better handle these (or if later.js handles them natively somehow):

- later.parse.recur().on(31).dayOfMonth()
  The date is the 31st of a given month. Current result is that is jumps months that end on the 30th. WORKAROUND: is to use last().dayOfMonth().
- later.parse.recur().on(30).dayOfMonth()
- later.parse.recur().on(31).dayOfMonth()
  Month of February, ending on the 28th or 29th. How to handle if the date is 30th (or 31st). WORKAROUND: If date > 28th, add .and().on(59).dayOfYear()

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of later.js, but apparently you can write something called a custom modifier: https://github.com/bunkat/later/blob/master/example/modifier.js

In addition to this, if you add a month to a javascript date (doesn't matter if the number becomes greater than 11/december), set the day of the month to the first then subtract 1 day, then you'll get the date of the last day in the originally given month. For example:

```js
var a = new Date("2000-02-25");
var b = new Date(new Date(a.getFullYear(),a.getMonth()+1,1)-1);
console.log(b);
```